# jQuery event on form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit, onchange, unbind

I need the same form to be submitted whether the user clicks on the submit button or selects a file to upload. I also need a warning to confirm if the user wants to navigate away without saving.

See http://jsfiddle.net/fuW2j/

When the submit button is clicked, the `beforeunload` event is unbound.

How can I make this happen for the file upload as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fuW2j/7/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="file"/>
```

**js**

```
$('input:file').change(function () {
    $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
    this.form.submit();
});
```

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inline pure JavaScript, handle the file change with jQuery too:

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
    $(this).parents("form").eq(0).trigger("submit");
});
```

And have only this:

```
<input type="file"/>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuW2j/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Using $('input').change(...) seems to work fine : http://jsfiddle.net/fuW2j/8/

```
(function() {

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        return 'Your changes have not been saved!';
    });

    $('input').change(function() {
        //$(window).unbind('beforeunload');
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
    });
})(jQuery);
```